# Java - set currentDate time in Native Query?

Tags: java, sql, datetime, nativequery

I have the following field in my entity:

```java
@JsonProperty
@Column(name = "updated")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Calendar updated;
```

I have the following Native query where I am trying to set the update date above:

```java
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
String updatedDate = dateFormat.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
    
String queryString = "update " + "persons" +
                     " set updated = " + updatedDate" +
                     " where person_id = 1";
```

But I am getting an error saying `incorrect datetime value`.

How can I set the value? It is `datetime` in the db.

Comment: Which database implementation are you using? Why are you using an outdated API for dates and time in java?

Comment: try surrounding updatedDate with apostrophes

Comment: A `DATETIME` in a database may require an offset, which would require you to alter the pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are really doing a raw JDBC update query, then you should be using a prepared statement here:

```sql
String sql = "UPDATE persons SET updated = ? WHERE person_id = 1";
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
java.util.Date date = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(date.getTime());
ps.setDate(1, sqlDate);
int numRowsAffected = ps.executeUpdate();
```

But you might want to consider migrating away from using `Calendar`, as it has been replaced by a new suite of date/time functions in Java 8.  Instead, consider replacing `Calendar` with `LocalDateTime`.

Answer (score -1):

try using this query. I see some syntax errors also in your query that is being finally formed.

```
String queryString = "update " + "persons" +
                     " set updated = '" + updatedDate + "' " +
                     " where person_id = 1";
```